# jekyll: how do i split the content into two parts?

Tags: jekyll

In my template I want to show a set of images in the middle of the content. So I'd imagine I need one part of the content then some images taken from the yaml, then the rest of the content meaning I'd have to split the content up into two parts.

How do I split the content up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and I solved it without splitting the content.
*I'll show the short version here, but there's a [post with a more detailed explanation](http://christianspecht.de/2014/08/22/jekyll-lightbox2-image-gallery-another-approach/) on my blog.*

I'm using [include files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes) for the actual work of displaying the gallery:

---

First of all, I'm using [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) to display the images, so I need to load some JS and CSS files (and jQuery) first. I want to do this only on the pages where I actually need Lightbox2, so I'm putting it into an include file, not into the layout file:

#### `/_includes/galheader.html` :

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

Then, I need another include file that displays the actual gallery:

#### `/_includes/gal.html` :

```
{% for image in page.images %}
    {% if include.image == null or include.image == image.name %}
        <a href="{{ page.imgfolder }}/{{ image.name }}" data-lightbox="1" title="{{ image.text }}">
            <img src="{{ page.imgfolder }}/{{ image.thumb }}" title="{{ image.text }}">
        </a>&nbsp;
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the `{% if include.image == null or ...` line allows me to use the include in two different ways:

1. Show all images:

   ```
   {% include gal.html %}
   ```
2. Show a single image:

   ```
   {% include gal.html image="image-1.jpg" %}
   ```

---

#### With those two includes, [I can now do this](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/code-examples/raw/2205198ffa5d99cbc40773a80366869450678f4c/jekyll-gallery-example/gallery-text1/index.md):

```
---
layout: default
title: Gallery with text (version 1)
imgfolder: /img/demopage
images:
  - name: image-1.jpg
    thumb: thumb-1.jpg
    text: The first image
  - name: image-2.jpg
    thumb: thumb-2.jpg
    text: The second image
  - name: image-3.jpg
    thumb: thumb-3.jpg
    text: The third image
---

{% include galheader.html %}

Some text here...and then, all the images in one single gallery:

{% include gal.html %}

...and more text after the gallery
```

#### [The generated HTML](http://jekyll-gallery-example.christianspecht.de/gallery-text1/):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<p><link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" /></p>

<p>Some text here...and then, all the images in one single gallery:</p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The first image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-1.jpg" title="The first image"></a></p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The second image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-2.jpg" title="The second image"></a></p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The third image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" title="The third image"></a></p>

<p>...and more text after the gallery</p>
```

---

#### Or I can [spread the images over the whole page](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/code-examples/raw/2205198ffa5d99cbc40773a80366869450678f4c/jekyll-gallery-example/gallery-text2/index.md):

```
---
layout: default
title: Gallery with text (version 2)
imgfolder: /img/demopage
images:
  - name: image-4.jpg
    thumb: thumb-4.jpg
    text: The 4th image
  - name: image-5.jpg
    thumb: thumb-5.jpg
    text: The 5th image
  - name: image-6.jpg
    thumb: thumb-6.jpg
    text: The 6th image
---

{% include galheader.html %}

Some text here, then two images:

{% include gal.html image="image-4.jpg" %}
{% include gal.html image="image-5.jpg" %}

...and more text...

Even more text and the last image:

{% include gal.html image="image-6.jpg" %}

Some text at the end
```

#### [The generated HTML](http://jekyll-gallery-example.christianspecht.de/gallery-text2/):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<p><link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" /></p>

<p>Some text here, then two images:</p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The 4th image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" title="The 4th image"></a></p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The 5th image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" title="The 5th image"></a></p>

<p>...and more text...</p>

<p>Even more text and the last image:</p>

<p><a href="/img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="1" title="The 6th image"><img src="/img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" title="The 6th image"></a></p>

<p>Some text at the end</p>
```